# Enviar mi checkbox false cuando no esta selecionado por un formulario angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Buen dia. Actualmente tengo un formulario reactivo en angular 7 que tiene 3 checkbox los cuales son: IsStudent, IsTeacher, IsSystem se pueden escojer los tres o dos o solo uno; Estos son perfiles. Esta informacion es enviada por medio de un post  a un api.

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label"
                for="isStudentUserID">Estudiante</label>

            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input class="form-control"
                id="isStudentUserID"
                type="checkbox"                        
                formControlName="isStudentUser" />    

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label"
                for="isTeacherUserID">Profesor</label>

            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input class="form-control"
                id="isTeacherUserID"
                type="checkbox"                            
                formControlName="isTeacherUser"
                ng-model="isTeacher" />    

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label"
                for="isSystemUserID">Sistemas</label>

            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input class="form-control"
                id="isSystemUserID"
                type="checkbox"                           
                formControlName="isSystemUser"  

                 />    

            </div>
        </div>        
      </div>
```

Cuando los tres checkbox estan seleccionados puedo guardar sin ningun problema pero cuando alguno de los tres no esta seleccionado el api me indica que debo enviar enviar ese campo. A continuacion anexo el metodo save

```
save() {    
let userVariable: IUser = Object.assign({}, this.formGroup.value);
this.userService.postUserschool(userVariable)
  .subscribe(level => this.onSaveSuccess(),
   error => console.error(error)); 
   }

onSaveSuccess(){
console.log("se creo correctamente");
this.router.navigate(['/userschool']);
```

}

Lo que necesito es una forma para que el formulario envie el input este o no seleccionado.

Aqui podemos ver por medio de consola que cuando no selecciono IsSystem no lo envia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en tu modelo de datos, esos campos son obligatorios ¿?

Comment: Si se refiere al api si son obligatorios enviarlos...

Comment: Pon el ts del componente, pero con incializarlos a false, debería de bastar.

Comment: Tienes razon los inicie con false por que cuando no se hace eso pasa " " en vez de pasar un true o false